# Windows Azure - Communicate between web site and VM without enabling external/remote access

Tags: azure

I'm new to Azure and have set up an Asure web site which will connect to a SOLR instance on an Azure VM. The web site cannot communicate with SOLR (port 8080) unless I create an endpoint. In order to create an endpoint I need to provide an internal and **external** port, however I do not want to allow external/remote access to SOLR, other than from the web site itself. Can anyone tell me how I should allow the web site to communicate with my VM, without making the VM publicly accessible?
Thank you,

JP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hhaggan stated, you cannot create a virtual network connection, or secure an endpoint, from Web Sites to a Virtual Machine. One option to consider is the use of SSL+certificate to secure the endpoint.

If you instead deploy your web application to a web role (in a cloud service) or a virtual machine, you can then take advantage of a brand new feature called Endpoint ACL. In essence, you can whitelist / blacklist a set of IP address ranges that may access your SOLR external endpoint. You can read about ACL'd endpoints, and how to configure them, [here](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/06/03/windows-azure-powershell-june-2013-update-for-iaas-and-paas/).

Now: You might be asking yourself why this doesn't work with Web Sites. That's because Web Sites runs on a server farm, and sites don't get unique IP addresses (unlike Cloud Services).

Answer (score 3):

if you are talking about Windows Azure Websites, I am not sure if this can be done but if you are talking about Web roles in Windows Azure Cloud service, here is something that I hope it can be beneficial.

Connect ASP.NET application to SQL Server in Windows Azure via Virtual Network http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj823135.aspx

you might also would like to have a look on this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-network/  I don't think you will need it but I am just sharing it with you, it is for WIndows Azure Virtual Network.

let me know if this solved your problems or if you need anything else.